# Is it really not possible to get data from IPromise?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-promise

I have a problem. I badly need a value that is inside my promise. I need to process it further. It is not possible for me to return promise.

My code:

```
function func(http: NpHttp, context: {
    obj: Obj
}) {
    var list: Obj[];
    const name = context.obj.name;
    var allowed = true;
    var result = http.get < ObjectList > ('/objects')
        .then(({
            data
        }) => {
            list = data.objects;
            console.log(list);
            return !list.some(t => t.name === name);
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log("Value: " + data);
            allowed = data;
            return data;
        });
    return () => allowed;
}
```

The value of allowed changes only inside callback, but not in general.
Please help

Comment: Yes, it's not possible to immediately return a value that will only become available in the future. Your only option is to return another promise.

Comment: So how could I return it when it is available?

Comment: You cannot make the function block to wait for that. Just return a promise that will fulfill with your result as soon as it is available.

Comment: I cannot return a promise, I need to have a boolean value

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: It's like ordering something on amazon... you have to wait until you receive your package before you can see what's inside it... :)